# How to kill a process from VC++

Tags: c++, windows, process, kill

Am using VC++ compiler i want to know how to kill a process. is there any functions.

i tried with TerminateProcess(); but i couldn't do...

Comment: Could you show us your code and be more explicit about what went wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exactly what you want to do but you have to know `TerminateProcess()` just kills the process without giving him a chance to close properly.

You might want first to send a `WM_CLOSE` message to the application and then, if it doesn't respond, kill it with `TerminateProcess()`.

Dr Dobbs has a **great** article (with samples) just [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/184416547).

You might want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

`TerminateProcess` requires the `PROCESS_TERMINATE` right.  If you're getting the process handle from `OpenProcess`, then the dwDesiredAccess parameter must at least include `PROCESS_TERMINATE`.

If you're trying to kill an elevated process, then your app (the app doing the killing) must also be elevated.

What error code are you getting from `GetLastError()`?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure you did it right:

- Use `OpenProcess` to get the process handle from a process ID (requesting `PROCESS_TERMINATE` access rights)
- Call `TerminateProcess` on this handle

What exactly went wrong with this approach?